# Spring MVC 3.0 CRUD application using annotation and jdbc template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I want to create a new application in Spring MVC, before start it, I want to learn how to use Spring MVC with annotations and JDBC template. I search many blogs and tutorials about that, but they are pretty much confusing as well.

Hopefully somebody could give me a good link where I could learn step by step for the annotation driven spring mvc application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at following series:

- [Barebones Spring MVC](http://www.earldouglas.com/barebones-spring-mvc/)
- [Articles about writing sample Spring Finance Manager](http://code.google.com/p/spring-finance-manager/)

Both have a git/svn repositories with working and complete code, so if you can't find something in article you may read the code :-)

Also I can't see any problems with using JDBC templates: it's just a way how you are implementing your [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) and nothing more. All other code interacts with DAO by interface and know nothing about implementation.

Very helpfull for me is to separate code to different [layers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_%28object-oriented_design%29) which of them interacts between each other, like in this picture:

[image: diagram of simple application]

(image stolen from http://www.captaindebug.com)

Spring provides even special annotations to allow grouping classes to layers. They are: `@Controller` for controllers, `@Service` for classes with business logic and `@Repository` for marking your DAOs.